# Displaying a Shapefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, shapefile

I have a [shapefile](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3fd6eb2de569477ca83b2b65da8ecb6f) that I want to display. I tried using matplotlib to display it, but I get this:
[image: What I Get]
However, when I tried to display using an online website I get this;
[image: What I Want]

How can I get the second image?

Here is my code:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Initializing Shapefile")
sf = shapefile.Reader("ap_abl")
apShapes = sf.shapes()
points = apShapes[3].points
print("Shapefile Initialized")

print("Initializing Display")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim([78, 79])
plt.ylim([19, 20])
print("Display Initialized")

print("Creating Polygon")
ap = plt.Polygon(points, fill=False, edgecolor="k")
ax.add_patch(ap)
print("Polygon Created")

print("Displaying polygon")
plt.show()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A Shapefile is a database of geometries. You have to render each one.

Comment: Sorry; I've removed my answer. I don't have time to both implement your solution and debug it. My comment above is still valid; you need to iterate over all the shapes in the Shapefile. Good luck!

Comment: Do you know how I can access a geometry?

Comment: Each Shape in the Shapefile database **is** a geometry. You are already accessing at least one of them! Did you just copy/paste this code from somewhere else without understanding what it's doing or what a Shapefile is?

Comment: I didn't understand what I shapefile is until now. I got all this code from documentations except the creation of the fig and ax variables.

Comment: I figured it out! sf.shapes has a list of all the geometries. The documentation used the 3rd index as a demonstration.

Comment: Bingo! It helps to read the documentation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that a shapefile has multiples shapes inside and I needed to plot all of them. From that, this is what works:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sf = shapefile.Reader("ap_abl")

print("Initializing Display")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim([76, 85])
plt.ylim([12, 21])
print("Display Initialized")

for shape in sf.shapes():
    print("Finding Points")
    points = shape.points
    print("Found Points")    

    print("Creating Polygon")
    ap = plt.Polygon(points, fill=False, edgecolor="k")
    ax.add_patch(ap)
    print("Polygon Created")

print("Displaying Polygons")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

Using GeoPandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shape=gpd.read_file('shapefile')
shape.plot()
```

Using pyshp and Descartes:

```
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import shapefile
sf=shapefile.Reader('shapefile')
poly=sf.shape(1).__geo_interface__
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.gca() 
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(poly, fc='#ffffff', ec='#000000', alpha=0.5, zorder=2 ))
ax.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

If the shapefile has multiple shapes then you can loop over `sf.shapes()` as discussed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202839/plotting-large-shapefiles-with-matplotlib/266675#266675).